# auto highlighting a row so original fill is retained on lost focus

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with columns which have background colour.  I wish to highlight a row when selecting a cell in it with a change in background colour.

The following code does this fine but does not restore the original background colour when I move to another line:

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Static rr

    If rr <> "" Then
        With Rows(rr).Interior
            .ColorIndex = xlNone
        End With
    End If


    r = Selection.Row
    rr = r

    With Rows(r).Interior
        .ColorIndex = 39
        .Pattern = xlSolid
    End With

End Sub
```

Please can anyone suggest a way I can alter the code to restore the original background when I move on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the previous format somewhere, then instead of setting `.ColorIndex = xlNone`, you restore the previous format.  The code below works by pasting the format into the last row of the sheet, then doing a Paste Special/Formats to restore it.  Not very elegant, but it does work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        Static lngPrevRow As Long
        Dim rngActiveCell As Range

        On Error GoTo errorHandler

        'prevent this code from triggering itself when it changes the selection
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'save active cell, as messing about with copy and paste will change the active cell
        Set rngActiveCell = ActiveCell

        If lngPrevRow <> 0 Then
                'paste saved format to previous row
                ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).Copy
                ActiveSheet.Rows(lngPrevRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

                'save current row's format at end of sheet
                ActiveSheet.Rows(rngActiveCell.Row).Copy
                ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                'tidy up
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Target.Select
        End If

        lngPrevRow = rngActiveCell.Row

        'highlight active row
        With ActiveSheet.Rows(rngActiveCell.Row).Interior
                .ColorIndex = 39
                .Pattern = xlSolid
        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        Exit Sub

errorHandler:
        'other error handling code here...
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Things to note:

- always declare variables as a type (e.g. `As Long`) - this prevents all kinds of subtle errors
- setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start speeds things up and prevents flickering (but remember to set it back to `True` at the end)
- this (as with your original code) doesn't handle multi-row selections very well.  It could be expanded to do so (e.g. by using `Target.EntireRow` instead of `ActiveSheet.Rows(rngActiveCell.Row)`), but with additional complexity (you'd need to store how many rows the previous selection was, etc etc).

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice but what you have suggested still doesn't get over the problem of losing background colours already present in certain columns.  I am not sure if there is a simple way of restoring the background colours by declaring them at the start?

Comment: The code copies the existing background before highlighting, then copies it back, so there shouldn't be any circumstances where it would lose the background.  Does my code work at all for you?  Is there anything unusual about the specific columns where it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for your response I have checked through again and realise I had left in my previous code by mistake.  Your solution works fine now thank you for your help.  Regards Eric

Comment: Sorry just checked again and your code leaves the last line selected recoloured when the file is closed and save changes check box is selected.

Comment: You could add code to the `BeforeSave` event handler that restored the format.  You'd need to move the `lngPrevRow` declaration into the module (so it was visible to all procedures, not just the `SelectionChange` one).  Then you could probably copy and paste the relevant bits of the code in the answer with only minor modification.